# Ajax call is loading two separate links, failing on the second link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to add search functionality to a web app by using Node.js and MongoDB with Mongoose. I have created a search form and am using the `onsubmit` attribute to load a function on the forms submission, where the AJAX call is. The goal is to reload a table with the returned data without reloading the entire webpage. I have the function set up to point to my controller and execute the search and return the results, however the AJAX call fails and also attempts to get two different locations (shown below - last box).

**HTML Form**

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return getSearchResults();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." type="text">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**AJAX Function**

```
<script>
    function getSearchResults(e) {
      var query = $("#searchInput").val();
      alert("Using AJAX call!");
      $.ajax({
        url: '/items/search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {"search": query},
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function(Results) {
          alert("Got the data");
        }
      }).fail(function(){
        alert("Oof big fail");
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
  itemController.search = function(req, res) {
    var searchQuery = (req.query.search);
    Item.find({ $or: [{name: searchQuery}, {category: searchQuery}, {subcategory: searchQuery}, {status: searchQuery}, {description: searchQuery}]}).exec(function (err, items) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
      }
      else {
        console.log(searchQuery);
        console.log("Search returning results");
        res.render("../views/items/items", {items: items});
      }
    });
  };
```

**Console Log with Two GET's**

```
Search returning results
GET /items/search?search=test 304 38.915 ms - -
GET /? 304 1.631 ms - -
```

The URL seems to be forming correctly, however I'm not sure why the second location `/?` is loaded and why the page refreshes since `e.preventDefault();` is at the end of my AJAX call. What should I be looking at in this instance?

**EDIT**

I went and removed the `e.preventDefault()` call within the AJAX request, along with `dataType: application/json`. Everything is now working as expected. Thanks to charlietfl! Updated code below.

**AJAX Function - Fixed**

```
function getSearchResults() {
  var query = $("#searchInput").val();
  alert("Using AJAX call!");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/items/search?search=' + query,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
      alert("Data got");
    }
  }).fail(function(){
    alert("Oof big fail");
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Should be seeing error in browser dev tools console that `e` is undefined when trying to call `e.preventDefault()`. Since that would occur before the `return` the form will submit by default process also

Comment: You're right, there was an error there. I went and got rid of the `e.preventDefault()` so that only `return false` is left (something I read in another thread) and it no longer attempts to load `/?`. However, the AJAX call still fails

Comment: OK...well that is a completely different issue. Inspect the actual request in dev tools network for clues. Note you don't do anything if there is a `find()` error

Comment: It looks like the call is successfully passing the data to the search controller, and the response the controller gives contains the data expected and formats it in the redirect call. I removed the line `dataType: application/json` within the AJAX call, and I got a successful return! Looks like that solves this issue, now on to reloading the data in the table. Thanks for your help! :D